# How do I ignore certain files while debugging in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I have debugging working in PHPStorm with Xdebug and my local apache webserver. I'm also using CodeSniffer to check my code style. CodeSniffer (phpcs.bat) is a tool you can enable in PHPstorm that is actually an external PHP script that runs every 3-5 seconds. The annoying thing is, whenever I have debug enabled (Listen for connections), it tries to debug the phpcs script even though it is not a part of my project. What's even odder is that phpcs is run via the php command line, NOT the apache server of which Xdebug is a part.

Is there anyway to stop phpStorm from debugging this external, command-line script?

Comment: Please check `Settings | PHP | Debug` -- there should be enough settings to skip/ignore such incoming debug requests.

Comment: Thanks, do you want to put that as an answer so you get karma points?

Comment: I'm fine, thnx. Plus .. I did not provide **exact** settings ... only a hint/general direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is to add the following parameters to the bat file that runs phpcs:

```
-d xdebug.remote_host="8.8.1.1" \
-d xdebug.remote_enable=0 \
-d xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

This sets custom PHP ini settings on the command line interface.

---

Alternately, go to `Settings | PHP | Debug` in PHPStorm and add a directory to the debug ignore list.

Answer (score 12):

You can ignore a file in PhpStorm in:

Preferences > PHP > Debug > Step Filters

Add it with the + sign in the skipped files section and navigate to the folder containing the file.

[image: phpStorm pref]

Answer (score 12):

There are settings in `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug` that allow you to remove the break-at-first-line behavior and ignore unregistered connections.
[image]

Comment: When working with XAMPP, this helps alot as it allows to ignore debug connection popup windows triggered by the phpMyAdmin bundled with XAMPP. Thanks! :-)

Comment: For phpcs and phpmd popping up when debugging, checking Ignore external... fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you land here and you have a *nix system you can consider using the following method:

- Disabling remote_autostart in your php.ini by using debug.remote_autostart=0
- Use one of the methods to enable the xdebug debugger on a session per session basis as [documented on this page](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#activate_debugger).
- I personally made an alias to easily start the debugger on the command line:

  ```
  $ alias enable_debugger='export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name"'
  ```

  This way you can easily enable the debugger for one command line session using the following command:

  ```
  $ enable_debugger
  ```